# Need suggestions for amaster thesis on wireless sensor systems

Tags: sensor, wireless, system

I am going to write my master thesis on a wireless sensor network for a fire security system. The wireless protocol is decided and confidential, and has mesh capabilities for redundancy and great battery life. Even so, the company I am writing it for wants to mainly get this new wireless system they want me to design commercialised, but I have to dig a bit deeper and do some thorough research on the subject.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what in such a wireless system I can do a research on, besides designing such a system?

Comment: Perhaps ask your thesis advisor.

Comment: Also, make sure any commercial arrangements are good to go.  In US universities, most would want this to be a formal arrangement.  Individual faculty members would have no authority to waive any university rights to the IP you generate as a functionary of the university.  If this is a private consulting arrangement between your mentor and a company, I think its even more important to get the school's blessing, to make sure nobody is taking advantage of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three universal research topics in Wireless Sensor Networks are:

1. Energy -- can never have enough!
2. Time Synchronization -- can never be tight enough!
3. Localization -- can never be accurate enough!

These are the three accepted areas of WSN where *any* improvement is heralded as a contribution. Pick something in there (I worked on the last one).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I suspected this question would possibly get closed. I was thinking about localization in terms of fighting problems with building obstruction and "wrong" RSSI vs distance.